# Is it possible to setQueryData using inclusive query key?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am unable to set query data using inclusive query keys using react query v4.

Example below which I want it to work, but won't

```
  const { data, isFetched, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery({
    retry: 4,
    retryDelay: 544,
    keepPreviousData: true,
    refetchOnMount: true,
    queryKey: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
    .....
  });

  /// WORKS
  queryClient.setQueriesData<InfiniteData<Data>>(
    ['key1'],
    (prev) => {
      if (!prev) return undefined;
      return {
        ...prev,
        pages: prev?.pages?.map((page) => updater(page)),
      };
    },
  );

  /// WORKS
  queryClient.setQueriesData<InfiniteData<Data>>(
    ['key1','key2'],
    (prev) => {
      if (!prev) return undefined;
      return {
        ...prev,
        pages: prev?.pages?.map((page) => updater(page)),
      };
    },
  );

  /// DOES NOT WORK!
  queryClient.setQueriesData<InfiniteData<Data>>(
    ['key2'],
    (prev) => {
      if (!prev) return undefined;
      return {
        ...prev,
        pages: prev?.pages?.map((page) => updater(page)),
      };
    },
  );
```

I want to have any keys in that exists within queryKey to work just like how invalidateQuery seems to function. Is this possible?

The docs states

"To update multiple queries at once and match query keys partially, you need to use queryClient.setQueriesData instead."

It seems it wants to match queries partially as in order matters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Understanding `setQueryData`'s functionality

`setQueryData` is used to directly set or update the data for a specific query based on the query key you give it. The query key provided in `setQueryData` needs to match the query key you used when making the query with `useQuery` or `useInfiniteQuery` hook exactly for it to update the cache correctly. This means if your query key in `useInfiniteQuery` is `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`, you need to use the same array as the query key in `setQueryData` to update the data of the query.

**Partial Matching:** `setQueryData` can indeed match query keys partially. However, this doesn't mean it disregards the order or the exact structure of the query keys. Partial matching usually refers to a scenario where you have multiple queries with keys like `['key1', 'key2']`, `['key1', 'key3']`, etc. In those cases, using `['key1']` with `setQueryData` can potentially update all queries that start with `['key1']`.

**Order Matters:** If the order in your `setQueryData` does not match the order in your `useInfiniteQuery`, it will not recognize it as the same query.

## Solution

You can check if [this solution from TkDodo works for your case](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/2078#discussioncomment-618852) or even [a better one](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/2078#discussioncomment-2069624).

---

**TLDR;**: In summary, for `setQueryData` to work as you intend, the query key used in `setQueryData` must match the structure and order of the key used in your query hook. Currently, React Query does not support partial matching without an exact key.

Comment: in your example, q1 = ['key1', 'key2'], q2=['key1', 'key3'], will q1 and q2 match the query ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `setQueryData` requires the query key to exactly match the structure and order of the key used in the query hook. The query key is treated as an exact match, According to the docs `setQueryData` supports partial match but only if it is an exact. Therefore q1 should update the query but q2 won't as it is not an exact match (doesn't follow the exact order of keys).

So if you do not have an exact match use `setQueriesData`. This should work for both q1 and q2.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good answer by [@loretta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11735399/loretta)

I just wanted to amend that order matters in arrays, but not in objects. So if you re-structure your queryKeys to be, for example:

```
queryKey: [{ key1: 'key1', key2: 'key2', key3: 'key3' }]
```

then you could in fact target them with:

```
queryClient.setQueriesData(
  [{ key2: 'key2' }],
  ...
)
```